# C# запись целочисленного массива в файл

Tags: c#

Нужно записать массив типа int в тестовый файл и другой функцией считать этот файл и вывести на экран.

Пример:

```
int[] pole = { 1055, 2, 29, 8, 7, 15, 29, 8, 22, 6, 29 };
```

В файле будет:

```
1055 2 29 8 7 15 29 8 22 6 29 (в одну строку)
```

Как не пробовал каждый раз числа выводит в столбец либо ошибка.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145856/how-to-join-int-to-a-character-separated-string-in-net

Comment: Покажите свой код, который выводит числа в столбец.

Answer (score 2):

Запись:

```
File.WriteAllText(fileName, string.Join(" ", pole));
```

Здесь используются следующие методы:

[`string.Join()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd992421(v=vs.110).aspx) - преобразует последовательность (массив в данном случае) в строку со вставкой между элементами строки-разделителя (в данном случае строка с одним пробелом `" "`);
[`File.WriteAllText()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms143375(v=vs.110).aspx) - записывает в файл (имя файла - первый параметр) строку (второй параметр) в кодировке UTF-8.

Чтение:

```
pole = Array.ConvertAll(File.ReadAllText(fileName).Split(), int.Parse);
```

Здесь используются следующие методы:

[`File.ReadAllText()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms143368(v=vs.110).aspx) - считывает из файла (имя - первый параметр) строку в кодировке UTF-8;
[`string.Split()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) - разбивает строку по пробельным символам и возвращает массив из кусочков;
[`Array.ConvertAll()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/exc45z53(v=vs.110).aspx) - берет массив (первый параметр) и применяет к каждому элементу указанный метод (второй параметр), из получившихся элементов собирает новый массив и возвращает его;
[`int.Parse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/b3h1hf19(v=vs.110).aspx) - получает число из его строкового представления (переданного в первом параметре).

Answer (score 0):

Склейте их в строку и запишите одной строкой.

```
var line = new int[] { 1055, 2, 29, 8, 7, 15, 29, 8, 22, 6, 29 }
              .Select(p => p.ToString())
              .Aggregate((p, j) => p + " " + j);
File.WriteAllLines("text.txt", new string[] { line });
```

При считывании используйте Split

```
foreach(var rline in File.ReadAllLines("text.txt"))
{
    rline.Split(' ').Select(p => int.Parse(p)).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Как-то усложнено.